# Why does \shipout start a new page?

Tags: tex-core, shipout

The Tex Book (20th printing, 1991) describes the `\shipout<box>` primitive as follows (p. 279).

> After the `<box>` is formed — possibly by constructing it explicitly and changing modes during the construction, as explained for `\hbox` earlier — its contents are sent to the dvi file

Based on this description, I would expect the pdf for the following plain TeX manuscript

```
\shipout\hbox{Hello, }%
\shipout\hbox{world!}%
\bye
```

to comprise a single page with the one-liner:

> Hello, world!

Instead, it comprises two pages:

1. > Hello,
2. > world!

Why?

Comment: Your expectation is wrong: every `\shipout` operation ships out a page.

Comment: `\shipout` is the _only_ way to make a new page in an output file as far as I know.

Comment: Do you mean the TeX Book?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Your expectations are not in line with TeX’s, I’m afraid. If you look at page 227, last doubly dangerous paragraph, you can read

> Sometimes you don't want TeX to defer a `\write` or
>   `\openout` or `\closeout`. You could say, e.g., ‘`\shipout\hbox{\write...}`’, but that would put an unwanted empty page in your `dvi` file.

*Every* `\shipout` operation ships out a page in the DVI file (or PDF, in case of `pdftex` with `\pdfoutput=1`).

With `\shipout<box>`, the box is built, then delivered in the proper format to the DVI (or PDF) file and finally removed from memory.

Note that `\shipout`, by itself, has no effect on the main vertical list: it's normally the output routine that manages it and usually calls `\shipout\box255` at the appropriate time, thus outputting a new page. So if you do

```
ABC

\shipout\hbox{DEF}

GHI

\bye
```

you will get *two* pages: one with “DEF” and the other one with the two lines “ABC” and “GHI”.